# Error when using Static in Struct

Tags: c++, static

Alright so I am pretty tired otherwise I would indepthly look up this problem, (I mean I have a little but nothing comes up that I am looking for)

I am trying to make these all my variables in my struct static because it needs to keep all the values to evaluate in another function.

(I will just post snippets of the code that is relevant) 
Here is my code, hopefully you can tell me what is up with this:

Error: 
unresolved external symbol "public: static wchar_t * gameLaunch::directory"

unresolved external symbol "public: static wchar_t * gameLaunch::AppName"

unresolved external symbol "public: static wchar_t * gameLaunch::ComboBoxName"

```
    struct gameLaunch
{
    int ID = 0;
    static wchar_t directory[MAX_PATH];
    static wchar_t AppName[MAX_PATH];
    static wchar_t ComboBoxName[MAX_PATH];

}gameLaunchtest;
```

---

```
gameLaunch test[100];
gameLaunch gameLaunchtest;
```

---

```
case IDB_CLICK_ME:
                {
                    GetWindowText(hProgramDirectory, gameLaunchtest.directory, MAX_PATH);
                    GetWindowText(hProgramName, gameLaunchtest.AppName, MAX_PATH);
                    GetWindowText(hProgramNameComboBox, gameLaunchtest.ComboBoxName, MAX_PATH);
                    wofstream launchLocations;
                    launchLocations.open("LaunchLocations.txt", std::ios_base::app | std::ios_base::out);
                    launchLocations << gameLaunchtest.directory << endl;
                    launchLocations << gameLaunchtest.AppName << endl;
                    launchLocations << gameLaunchtest.ComboBoxName << endl;

                    ComboBox_AddString(comboBox, gameLaunchtest.directory);
                    launchLocations.close();
                    break;
```

---

```
case IDB_CLICK_ME_AGAIN:
                    int selectedNumber = 0;
                    while (true)
                    {
                        selectedNumber = ComboBox_GetCurSel(comboBox);


                            if (test[number].ID = selectedNumber)
                            {
                                ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", test[number].AppName, NULL, test[number].directory, 5);

                            }
                            number = number + 1;

                    }
                break;
```

Comment: Ops sorry I forgot to post that, I will update the thread.

Comment: static acts as a declaration. Definition of wchar_t gameLaunch::directory[MAXPATH]; needs to be separately added outside the struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare static fields outside of your class/struct. It should be done in the following way:

```
wchar_t gameLaunch::directory[MAXPATH];
wchar_t gameLaunch::AppName[MAXPATH];
wchar_t gameLaunch::ComboBoxName[MAXPATH];
```